# Не могу добавить Inline кнопки для телеграм бота. Не добавляются кнопки "bkt"

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
                                              ## markup.py ##

from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# кнопки главного меню
item1 = KeyboardButton('1')
item2 = KeyboardButton('2')
item3 = KeyboardButton('3')
item4 = KeyboardButton('4')
menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).row(item1, item2).row(item3, item4)

# инлайн кнопка 1
inline_ikb1 = InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='ikb1')
inline_ikm = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).row(inline_ikb1)

`# после нажатия кнопки 1, выберите одну из 3-х кнопок
inline_bkt1 = InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='bkt1')
inline_bkt2 = InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='bkt2')
inline_bkt3 = InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='bkt3')
bkt = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(inline_bkt1, inline_bkt2, inline_bkt3)`


                                              ## bot.py ##

import config
import logging
import markup as mar

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# кнопки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text, reply_markup=mar.menu)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def content_next(message: types.Message):

    `# кнопка 1
    if message.text == '1': 
        await message.answer('Вы нажали кнопку 1, а так же кнопку в чате', reply_markup=mar.inline_ikm)`

    # кнопка 2
    elif message.text == '2':
        await message.answer('Вы нажали кнопку 2')

    # кнопка 3
    elif message.text == '3':
        await message.answer('Вы нажали кнопку 3')

    # кнопка 4
    elif message.text == '4':
        await message.answer('Вы нажали кнопку 4')
    else:
        await message.answer('Пожалуйста нажимайте на кнопки, а то я вас не понимаю :)')

# запускаем лог поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `InlineKeyboardMarkup()` не принимает значения `resize_keyboard=True`. Просто замените все `InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)` на `InlineKeyboardMarkup()`. Лучше всего, вам стоит взглянуть в [документацию](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)

Comment: Если есть недопонимания, то можно взглянуть на лучшее пособие по [кнопкам в aiogram](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/buttons/)